# There is no Riemann Metric on $R^2$ inducing the sup-distance

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to show that there does not exist a Riemann metric $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which induces the distance $d_\infty(p,q)=\|p-q\|_\infty$, but am not entirely sure how to procede.

My first attempt was to use that $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $d_\infty$ is a complete metric space and thus if there exists such a metric a complete riemannian manifold so there exists a minimal geodesic between any two points $p,q$, and use this to somehow arrive at a contradiction. The somehow part is unfortunately evading me...

Any ideas how to procede, or alternative approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundary of the unit ball  in this metric is not a submanifold, because actually it is a square. Riemann metric is smooth, so unit ball should be a submanifold.

Comment: Thanks,  I was considering that approach. But I found I could not answer "why isnt it a submanifold?". I mean the topology induced by $d_\infty$ and $d_2$ are the same, so what changes?

Comment: You can think about it in this way: function $f(x;y)=d_{\infty}((x;y),(0;0))=|x|+|y|$ should be smooth if it is induced by metric - that is obviusly false.

Comment: The distance function is always continuous, but is it always smooth?

Comment: It is not smooth in some critical isolated points

Comment: I mean; you claim that f should be smooth because it is induced by the metric. The riemannian metric might be smooth, but f is defined from the distance function and not directly from the metric; is it completely obvious thay the distance function on a manifold is a smooth map? See for instance: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21295/smoothness-of-distance-function-in-riemannian-manifolds